# PHP foreach prints out forms | all forms are submitted to one ajax code, but just the first form works

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have like four forms looking like:

```
<form id='request_form' method='post'>
<input type=hidden id='currency_form' value='$currency'>
<center><input type=submit class='bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-400 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border-b-4 border-blue-700 hover:border-blue-500 rounded' value=Request></center>
</form>
```

And my ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#request_form').on('submit', function(e){
var currency = $("#currency_form").val();

var ajax_data = '{ "currency" : "'+ currency +'"}';

e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submit.php",
    cache: false, 
    dataType: "json",
    data: ajax_data,
    success: function(data) {
    if (data.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("deposit_message").className = "text-center text-green-500"; 
        document.getElementById("deposit_message").innerHTML = data.message;
    }
    else if(data.status == 201)  {
        document.getElementById("deposit_message").className = "text-center text-red-500"; 
        document.getElementById("deposit_message").innerHTML = data.message;
    }
    else if(data.status == 202) {
        document.getElementById("deposit_message").className = "text-center text-red-500"; 
        document.getElementById("deposit_message").innerHTML = data.message;
    }
}
});
});
});
```

Just the first form gets submitted via ajax. When I click the second or the third the sites just reloads.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: You can not use the same HTML-id twice or more on one page.

Comment: How to get multiple ID working with just one script?

Comment: If you got mutliple sections around your forms you can get it like this ´$('.global_section_class .submite_form_btn').on('click', ...)´

Answer (score 0):

Replace `id` attribute to `class` attribute:

```
<form class='request_form' method='post'>
<input type=hidden class='currency_form' value='$currency'>


$('.request_form').on('submit', function(e){
```

And to access the fields use class before the field:

```
var currency = $(".request_form .currency_form").val();
```

This is necessary to inform to the browser which element you want to submit.